# How to derive a discriminated union from another type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say we have an object of type

```
const originalObj = { foo: 'fooVal', bar: 'barVal' };
```

How do I write a utility type to create a discriminated union from the original object so that each member would look like

```
type Sample1 = {
  header: string;
  accessor: 'foo' //discriminant
  render?: (value: 'fooVal', original: typeof originalObj) => React.ReactNode;
};

type Sample2 = {
  header: string;
  accessor: 'bar' //discriminant
  render?: (value: 'barVal', original: typeof originalObj) => React.ReactNode;
};
```

If I created it manually, what I want would would look like

```
type OriginalObjMappedToUnIonOfSamples = Sample1 | Sample2;
```

How do I write a helper to automatically create this for me when only given the original object type? Maybe something like

```
type WhatIWant = GetDiscriminatedUnionOfSamples<typeof originalObj>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *mapped type* which maps each key in `originalObj` to its corresponding object type. Indexing the result with `keyof T` will produce the result you are looking for.

```
type GetDiscriminatedUnionOfSamples<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    header: string;
    accessor: K;
    render?: (value: T[K], original: typeof originalObj) => React.ReactNode;
  };
}[keyof T];
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd5pgBzYGlAGwHkAjAKzgBeOAG84mCBABcBCRABqnfABo4PFFBn51URR3xwAvhXIwAnmCRwA4khgARYHTRRQbFDCQATAKo1gtFyYAMoo4BxIdAA8ACoAfEKi5HBwANoA0nBscADWSGYQmHAxALoyIskpcAAWqF5ImnAMrjTMFFVw6GiRdNAy6e1VRDT1UAD8MgAUAG6cAK5IMjEZJapMrOwcMuaWhXDr7tz8AJRCCcjoMAB0FxgAchD1g8bkhql5BUWlJjtWAOrVDwAST+KBo8GEtgcThcbnYnl8-kCITCYAi0V+ewOm14fDiFCAA)

Comment: The `[keyof T]` at the end was what I missing. Could you explain or point me to the docs what that does?

Comment: It is an [Indexed Access Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). They are usually used to get the type of a property of an object type using a *string literal type* as shown in the docs. But you can also supply a union like `keyof T` which will result in a union of all property types of `T`